# Proving an orthonormal theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

> Theorem 10: If $\{u_1,...,u_p\}$ is an orthonormal basis for a
>   subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $proj_Wy= (y \cdot u_1)u_1 + ...
>  + (y \cdot u_p)u_p$. If $U =[u_1 \ \ \ u_2  \ \ \    u_p]$  ,then $proj_W y = UU^Ty$ for all $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$
>
> $proj_Wy= (y \cdot u_1)u_1 + ... + (y \cdot u_p)u_p$ shows that
>   $proj_Wy$ is a linear combination of the columns of $U$ using the
>   weights $y \cdot u_1 + ... + y \cdot u_p$ The weights can be written
>   as $u^T_1y,...,u^T_py$ showing that they are the entries in $U^Ty$.

I don't see how $y \cdot u_1 + ... + y \cdot u_p$ is obtained. If we distribute the $u_i$ in the equation, wouldn't it be $proj_Wy= yu + ... + yp$?

Comment: What do you mean with that ">" symbol there? Those are vectors, so how is one of them "bigger" than other one?

Comment: Removed it. Sorry that was from the quoting format (> at every line)

Comment: I still have problems understanding this: what **exactly** is that $\;U\;$ there? Apparently a mapping because of the following $\;UU^T\;$ , but how is it defined? As a matrix and thus are $\;u_1,...,u_p\;$ its columns?

Comment: Sorry again, U is an orthonormal matrix

Answer (score 0):

It is the definition of the projection, that is how it is defined. But here is a bit of intuition behind the definition:

Suppose you have $2$ vectors in 3D space, then their inner product is defined like this:
[image]

Notice that the length of the projection of $\vec{a}$ on $\vec{b}$ is
$$|\vec{a}_{proj}| = |\vec{a}|\cdot \cos \theta = \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|} $$
Maybe a picture will help:

[image]

$\vec{a}_{proj}$ points at same direction of $\vec{b}$ so if $|\vec{b}|=1$, meaning $b$ is a unit vector, then
$$\vec{a}_{proj} = |\vec{a}_{proj}| \vec{b} =  \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{|\vec{b}|} \vec{b} = (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}) \vec{b} $$

Now, if you want to project a vector $\vec{a}$ on a plane spanned by the orthonormal basis $\{\vec{b_1},\vec{b_2}\}$. just project the vector on each of the vectors in the basis and add the projections.